# why cout<<lower; and cout<<v.begin; alone are giving error , but cout <<(lower.begin()); is not giving any error and make the code to compile easily

Tags: c++, vector

In the last second line of the code :

```
vector<int> v;
cin>>n;
vector<int>::iterator lower;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>b;
    v.push_back(b);
}
cin>>t;
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    cin>>a;
    lower=lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),a);
    cout<<(lower-v.begin())<<endl;
}
```

what is the difference that makes `cout<<lower;` and `cout<<v.begin();` alone contribute to error but `cout<<(lower-v.begin());` make program to compile easily.

Comment: Printing an iterator is a bit meaningless, but printing the difference (i.e. distance) between two iterators is just an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of what overload resolution finds.

There isn't (by default) an overload of `<<` that matches `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector<int>::iterator)`. You can write one if you wish.

There is an overload of `<<` that matches `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector<int>::difference_type)`, and there is an overload of `-` that matches `std::vector<int>::difference_type operator-(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)`

You can break that line down into

```
std::vector<int>::difference_type diff = lower - v.begin(); // some number
std::cout << diff << std::endl; // print the number
```

Comment: please clarify what u have said. it is not understandable.